# How to divide wav file into frames uding MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a .wav file and I need to perform STFT on it. Say I dont know the length of the file. How can I break it into smaller frames and perform STFT??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a long time since I last worked on MatLab, but I think the general algo should be:

1. Take the input signal.
2. Multiply point-by-point with a windowing function (say rectangular of 'n' samples). This means you will now have a frame of 'n' samples.
3. Take an FFT of this frame.
4. Move the window by 'm' samples (m = shift, usually about 25% of 'n'). Do steps 2 and 3.
5. If end of signal is reached, take however many samples of the signal you get and fill the rest with zeros. Do steps 2 and 3.
6. You now have a 3D plot - frequency, amplitude and time. Plot to get STFT.

On a side note: Are there no STFT functions in MatLab? Have you checked?

Comment: Well thank you. I'm kind of still learning MATLAB, so would it be possible for you to write the code for steps 2 and 4???? Would be really REALLY helpful....
And no, there's no unique function for stft.

Comment: By the way regardless of the length of my wav file, can i take say 1024 samples??

Comment: you can take 1024 samples. but make sure that if you reach end of file, you would need to pad the left-over samples with zeros.